Flutter app crash while playing video, How to fix that?
In flutter application I have some video and some image on feed which is comes from API. While I'm scrolling the feed, application crash after sometime.
Also in debug mode and release mode, in both mode application crash after some time and they send me some logs which i mention below.
Code for feed:
return InViewNotifierList(
          controller: _scrollController,
          itemCount: homeController.feedPostList.length + (homeController.isLastPage.value ? 0 : 1),
          initialInViewIds: ['0'],
          isInViewPortCondition: (double deltaTop, double deltaBottom, double viewPortDimension) {
            return deltaTop < (0.4 * viewPortDimension) && deltaBottom > (0.3 * viewPortDimension);
          },
          builder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                homeController.feedPostList[index].feedType!.toLowerCase() == "image"
                    ? FeedImageView(userFeedPost: homeController.feedPostList[index])
                    : InViewNotifierWidget(
                  id: '$index',
                  builder: (context, isInView, child) {
                    return VideoWidget(
                      thumbnailUriSmall: homeController.feedPostList[index].thumbnailUriSmall!,
                      thumbnailUriLarge: homeController.feedPostList[index].thumbnailUriLarge!,
                      play: isInView,
                      url: homeController.feedPostList[index].contentUri!,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );

Here is VideoWidget, which have chewie player for playing video.
class VideoWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  final bool play;
  final String thumbnailUriLarge;
  final String thumbnailUriSmall;

  const VideoWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.url,
    required this.play,
    required this.thumbnailUriLarge,
    required this.thumbnailUriSmall,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoWidgetState createState() => _VideoWidgetState();
}

class _VideoWidgetState extends State<VideoWidget> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  ChewieController? _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initVideoPlayer();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(VideoWidget oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (oldWidget.play != widget.play) {
      if (_chewieController != null) {
        if (widget.play) {
          _chewieController!.play();
        } else {
          _chewieController!.pause();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void _initVideoPlayer() async {
    try {
      _controller = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(Uri.parse(widget.url));
      await _controller.initialize();
      _chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: _controller,
        autoInitialize: true,
        autoPlay: widget.play,
        looping: true,
        allowFullScreen: false,
        showControls: false,
        placeholder: const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
      setState(() {});
      print("Controller initialized");
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error initializing video: $e");
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _chewieController?.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _chewieController != null && _chewieController!.videoPlayerController.value.hasError
        ? const Center(
      child: Text("Error"),
    )
        : _chewieController != null && _chewieController!.videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized
        ? AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
      child: Chewie(
        controller: _chewieController!,
      ),
    ) : Center(
      child: CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: widget.thumbnailUriLarge,
        errorWidget: (context, error, stackTrace) => CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: widget.thumbnailUriSmall,
          errorWidget: (context, error, stackTrace) => const Center(
            child: Text("Temporary video is not available"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```


Basically i'm use InViewNotifierWidget for playing video. in VideoWidget, play variable is from InViewNotifierWidget. So, when video is comes at decided are video play otherwise video pause.

Whenever application crash, i got
W/com.app.( 3621): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 65548 byte allocation with 371000 free bytes and 362KB until OOM, target footprint 201326592, growth limit 201326592" (VmSize 2037760 kB)

and 

I/com.app.( 3621): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/com.app.( 3621): Clamp target GC heap from 215MB to 192MB



I try with Future, cache, isolate but still application crash. So, is there any other solution for that or same solution which i tried but different way?


Hi,
it's related to freeing some storage, trying to remove other applications that is not required and trying again to play the video.

Hello @DhruvanBhalara, Thank you for your reply. but still not working.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
